# SQLAlchemy maria Db column encoding problem

Tags: dataframe, encoding, sqlalchemy, mariadb, decoding

I am pulling a table from a maradb database using SQL Alchemy like so:

```
engine=db.create_engine('mariadb+mariadbconnector://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?charset=utf8mb4')
```

then create the connection

```
connection = engine.connect()
```

I then add a select statement and put the table in a pandas data frame

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
objects = text(''' SELECT * FROM objects 0
INNER JOIN area a ON a.id =o.area_id LIMIT 10;''')
raw = pd.read_sql(objects,connection)
```

So far so good, but when I access the data frame the uuid column is in the bellow format

```
0    b'\x05\xd5\x0b\x80\xf4\x05O\xd3\x9e\x17\x88\xb5p\xca\x8d6'
1                b'Q\xddJ\xd6y\xdeOG\xad\xdc\xbc@\xb5,\xfe\x08'
2            b'z\xde\xb7\xb8\x160O\xc9\x80\x0b\x96\xbaR\x04k\r'
3                b'\xeb\x7f\xb9~\xa8\x0eO\x9f\x87\xea`@\x16)QD'
4             b'\x051\xc1\x81\xbf\xe2O!\xa3AT\xa1\xf7X\x92\xbc'
5                      b'\x1c\x00x\x99\xbbQO\xc9\xbdZ\xccb(K5b'
6                b'DFg\xa7_\xfeO\xe3\x95\x95-u\xd7\xed\x90\xd8'
7         b'\x91\xba\xe0\xe2\x1c\xe7OS\xbbW\x0b\xcd\t\x85V\xf0'
8             b'`\xdb\xd7\xba~\xdeO\xb2\xa5\xcd)\x00\xa5&\xa0,'
9               b'%\x06\xf5<_\xa7O\x08\x9c\x90\n|t\xc8\x95\xdc'
```

Going back to the database and executing the same query I get the bellow result in the uuid column

```
1    Õ  ô OÓ   µpÊ 6
2   QÝJÖyÞOG­Ü¼@µ,þ 
3   zÞ·¸ 0OÉ   ºR k 
4   ë ¹~¨ O  ê`@ )QD
5    1Á ¿âO!£AT¡÷X ¼
6     x »QOÉ½ZÌb(K5b
7   DFg§_þOã  -u×í Ø
8    ºàâ çOS»W Í  Vð
9   `Û×º~ÞO²¥Í) ¥& ,
10  % õ<_§O    |tÈ Ü
```

I understand I am having an encoding problem and I tried decoding-encoding like bellow

```
raw.uuid.str.encode('utf-8')
```

but I am stuck. Any pointers are much appreciated. On how I can fix this problem on the source or at least at the data frame lvl.

Comment: Hey there! You should check what encoding the db uses as defaults and which tables use what for their columns:  ```SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA``` . maybe this helps right away.

Comment: For default_character_set_name I get utf8mb4 and default_collation_name I get utf8mb4_general_ci but when I add to charset in the db connection still no change.

Comment: try a different connector, such as "mysql+pymysql://" and "utf8" instead of "utf8mb4". I know thats just 2 more things you can try and error, but it might make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MariaDB Connector/Python sets utf8mb4 by default and doesn't accept another character set.
2. Since the result is a binary object, the uuid was stored in a blob (binary) column. Instead of trying to encode it, you need to convert it to a string:

```
>>>import uuid
    
>>>uuid.UUID(bytes=b'\x05\xd5\x0b\x80\xf4\x05O\xd3\x9e\x17\x88\xb5p\xca\x8d6')
UUID('05d50b80-f405-4fd3-9e17-88b570ca8d36')
```